# Fail to build MongoDB replcaset with Auth on Swarm

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-swarm, replicaset

I'm trying to create a MongoDB cluster on a docker swarm with authentication.
(My process work when auth is disabled)

So I have 3 mongo instance (started with option `--auth --replicaset REPLICASET_NAME`)on the same crypted overlay network. (mongo1, mongo2 and mongo3)

On node with mongo1 container I initiate the replicaset and create the db admin

```
docker exec -ti $(docker ps -f "name=mongo1" -q) mongo
> rs.initiate()
{
        "info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set",
        "me" : "84ab8d1609c8:27017",
        "ok" : 1
}
REPLICASET_NAME:SECONDARY> use admin
switched to db admin
REPLICASET_NAME:PRIMARY> db.createUser({ user: "myUserAdmin", pwd: "123456", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]})
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "myUserAdmin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}
REPLICASET_NAME:PRIMARY> exit
```

After that I create the clusterAdmin

```
docker exec -ti $(docker ps -f "name=mongo1" -q) mongo -u myUserAdmin --authenticationDatabase "admin" -p
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin
MongoDB server version: 3.4.1
REPLICASET_NAME:PRIMARY> db.createUser({user: "myClusterAdmin", pwd: "123456", roles: [ { role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" } ]})
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "myClusterAdmin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "clusterAdmin",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}
REPLICASET_NAME:PRIMARY> exit
```

Now when I used the clusterAdmin to add replicaset member, I have an error

```
docker exec -ti $(docker ps -f "name=mongo1" -q) mongo -u myClusterAdmin -p
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.1
REPLICASET_NAME:PRIMARY>rs.add("mongo2")
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: c4fe398cc7b8:27017;
the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: mongo2:27017 failed with not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetHeartbeat: \"REPLICASET_NAME\", pv:
1, v: 2, from: \"c4fe398cc7b8:27017\", fromId: 0, checkEmpty: false }",
    "code" : 74,
    "codeName" : "NodeNotFound"
}
```

So I have a "NodeNotFound" error but I can ping mongo2 from mongo1 and the mongo2 respond

```
docker exec -ti $(docker ps -f "name=mongo1" -q) mongo --host mongo2 -u myUserAdmin  -p
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://mongo2:27017/
MongoDB server version: 3.4.1
2017-01-12T16:09:34.043+0000 E QUERY    [main] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1459:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
```

So do you know why it's not working ?
I did something stupid :p ?

Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a solution. 
Just I use a keyfile to authenticate each mongo nodes. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/

But this is useless beceause of the crypted network overlay created by swarm.